# What is the difference between the switch and match syntax?

Tags: switch-statement, match

Some languages have a `switch` expression/statement and some have a `match` statement. Is there a difference in this semantically, or is it just a different syntax for something that is fundamentally the same.

For example:

Rust has `match`:

```
match coin {
    Coin::Penny => 1,
    Coin::Nickel => 5,
    Coin::Dime => 10,
    Coin::Quarter(state) => 25,
}
```

(Taken from https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#the-match-control-flow-operator.)

Java has switch:

```
switch coin {
    case Penny:
        return 1;
        break;
    case Nickel:
        return 5;
        break;
    case Dime:
        return 10;
        break;
    case Quarter:
        return 25;
        break;
}
```

(A piece of equivalent code.)

Comment: It is the same. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: They're just words.  To find out what they do in any particular language, you have to read the documentation of that language; nothing in programming is ever universal across all possible languages.  That said, Rust probably chose the word `match` instead of `switch` deliberately to emphasize the differences with `switch` in certain other languages; for instance, the requirement that the arms be exhaustive.

Comment: Something with [such constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) that can differ between languages or even versions of the same language, is whether each case must be a constant literal, or can be a variable or is allowed to be some type of "pattern" that can be matched or not matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat: this varies wildly depending on the language, of course.
Here I'll work with the Java `switch` statement, since it's a commonly-used language and its `switch` semantics seem roughly representative.

A few key differences are:

- `match` is exhaustive (i.e. you have to be able to prove to the compiler that exactly one branch is matched)
- `match` is an *expression* (although arguably this is more a Rust feature than a `match` feature), i.e.:

```rust
let x = 123;
let s = match x {
  0 => "zero",
  1 => "one",
  _ => "something else",
};
println!("{}", s);  // prints "something else"
```

- `match` performs destructuring:

```rust
let x = Some(123);
let s = match x {
  None => "nothing".to_string(),
  Some(x) => format!("the number: {}", x),
};
println!("{}", s);  // prints "the number: 123"
```

However, you really should take a look at the docs for `match` and compare them to the docs for the relevant `switch` feature in another language. These are just the obvious differences when comparing against C-like switches.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference in implementations is not mentioned yet: In many languages (to my knowledge at least Java, C#, C++, JavaScript) the switch statement acts more like a GOTO than actual branch arms. This is why in such languages you have to end each "arm" with a `break;`. If you didn't the code of the next `case` would also be executed.

Here is a small example:

```java
int x = 1;
int y = 0;
switch x {
    case 0:
      y = -1; // gets skipped
    case 1:
      y += 1; // switch jumps to here
    case 2:
      y -= 1;  // then continues here
}
assert y == 0;
```

This is a difference by convention only, it is not an intrinsic difference between `match` and `switch`. Eg in Go, `switch` actually matches only a single arm.

It allows for some very convoluted logic to be succinctly expressed, but it is also an easy source for bugs because reordering `case` statements could change your program if you didn't spot the absence of a `break`.